# Loop through array with wildcard for element name

Tags: php, arrays, wildcard

I am working a Rightmove BLM file and converting it into an array which is working fine.

However, the images are stored in sequential element nodes MEDIA_IMAGE_00, 01, 02 etc..

I am wondering if someone can advise me the best way to loop though those sequential elements using a wildcard or similar MEDIA_IMAGE_* for example.

Example of struture:

```
[MEDIA_IMAGE_00] => 003436_RX78401_IMG_00.jpg 
[MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_00] => 
[MEDIA_IMAGE_01] => 003436_RX78401_IMG_01.jpg 
[MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_01] => 
[MEDIA_IMAGE_02] => 003436_RX78401_IMG_02.jpg 
[MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_02] => 
[MEDIA_IMAGE_03] => 003436_RX78401_IMG_03.jpg
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Start by showing us an example of your actual data structure.

Comment: Assuming the numbering always starts from 0 and there are no "holes" in it - just increase a counter variable inside a loop, format that to two digits with a leading zero, append it to the "prefix" `MEDIA_IMAGE_`, and check if an array element with that key actually exists ... When you find the first one that doesn't exist, you can stop looping.

Comment: Or stick those values into a sub-array to begin with while you are creating this data structure, then you can loop over that directly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution might be:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$image)
{
   if(str_contains($key, 'MEDIA_IMAGE_'))
   {
       //$image is your filename for the current image
   }
}
```

But you can use RegEx instead.
In this case you just change the condition of the if to something like:

```
preg_match('/MEDIA_IMAGE_\d\d/', $key) === 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter()` in combination with an own filter-function.

### Example

```php
$inputArray['MEDIA_IMAGE_00'] = '003436_RX78401_IMG_00.jpg';
$inputArray['MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_00'] =  '';
$inputArray['MEDIA_IMAGE_01'] = '003436_RX78401_IMG_01.jpg';
$inputArray['MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_01'] = '';
$inputArray['MEDIA_IMAGE_02'] = '003436_RX78401_IMG_02.jpg';
$inputArray['MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_02'] = '';
$inputArray['MEDIA_IMAGE_03'] = '003436_RX78401_IMG_03.jpg';

var_dump($inputArray);

/*
array(7) {
  ["MEDIA_IMAGE_00"]=>
  string(25) "003436_RX78401_IMG_00.jpg"
  ["MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_00"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MEDIA_IMAGE_01"]=>
  string(25) "003436_RX78401_IMG_01.jpg"
  ["MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_01"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MEDIA_IMAGE_02"]=>
  string(25) "003436_RX78401_IMG_02.jpg"
  ["MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_02"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MEDIA_IMAGE_03"]=>
  string(25) "003436_RX78401_IMG_03.jpg"
}
*/

$inputArray = array_filter($inputArray, function($key) {
    return preg_match('/MEDIA_IMAGE_\d\d/', $key) === 1;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

var_dump($inputArray);
/*
array(4) {
  ["MEDIA_IMAGE_00"]=>
  string(25) "003436_RX78401_IMG_00.jpg"
  ["MEDIA_IMAGE_01"]=>
  string(25) "003436_RX78401_IMG_01.jpg"
  ["MEDIA_IMAGE_02"]=>
  string(25) "003436_RX78401_IMG_02.jpg"
  ["MEDIA_IMAGE_03"]=>
  string(25) "003436_RX78401_IMG_03.jpg"
}
*/
```

If you just want to filter out empty values, you can even use `filter_array()` without any custom function. See the documentation for more information.

### Documentation

[array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) in php documentation.